# json variable in to HTML table in API

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

please help me to API data display in a table. following error has occur 
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\api\index.php on line 32

```
<?php

$username = "368501B084C26A480A7F728E416";
$password = "E8F14846445248890038867E3FB";

$k = $username.":".$password;

$API_ACCESS_TOKEN = base64_encode ($k);        

$curl_handle = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.jgeposnowbjj.com/api/product/9142842');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Authorization: Basic ' . $API_ACCESS_TOKEN,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
));


$buffer = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);

///Deocde Json
$data = json_decode($buffer,true);

             $total=count($data);
             $Str='<h1>Total </h1> : '.$total.'';
             echo $Str;


             foreach ($data as $key => $value)
              {
          echo '  <td><font  face="calibri"color="red">'.$value["ProductID"].'   </font></td>
                  <td><font  face="calibri"color="blue">'.$value["Name"].'   </font></td>
                  <td><font  face="calibri"color="green">'.$value["CostPrice"].'   </font></td>
                  <td><font  face="calibri"color="green">'.$value["SalePrice"].'   </font></td>
                  </tr><tr>';

           }
           echo "</tr></table>";

?>
```

Comment: try to put print_r($data) value before the loop and see if you got those keys (e.g. "ProductID") at all. I suspect this API is having a running variable before the key